# How to "NaN" a range of data when a given criteria is met for a given period of time

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have a pd.dataframe which contains activity count data from a Philips Actiwatch. When there is no activity count for a period of more than 60 minutes, the user was probably not wearing the device, and this range should be removed.

How do I detect periods of >60 min (each line is 1 minute) in my Dataframe and remove that complete period. Thus, if the activity count is 0 for 59 lines or less, nothing happens, but if the activity count is 0 for 60 lines or more (let's say 80 lines), this data should be NaN.

The csv file with the data can be found here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6h43nrozohc9vd8/Actiwatch%20Data?dl=0

Pretty useless as it is, this is where I got stuck:

```
# remove all data where Activity = 0 for 60 or more consecutive minutes: 

zero_count = 0
for n in range(len(data)):
    if data['Activity'].loc[n] == NaN:
        continue
    elif data['Activity'].loc[n] > 0:
        continue
    elif data['Activity'].loc[n] = 0:
        while data['Activity'].loc[n] = 0:
            zero_count = zero_count + 1
        if zero_count >60: 
            # NaN last zero_count number of lines.
            zero_count = 0
            break
        else:
            zero_count = 0
            break
    else:
        print "Non-wear detection error"
        break
```

What I was trying to do is check each line, if it is 0, it should add +1 to the "zero_count" and when a non-zero digit is read, it should check whether the zero_count is >60, if it is, it should NaN the whole range and reset the zero_count. If it is <60, the zero_count should just be reset without NaN-ing any data.

I hope anyone understand what I am trying to do and either: 1) make the code above work, or 2) have a better idea for doing what I am trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  were close, but you have an infinate loop in your code. as well as some of the logic in your if statement is a bit off. Here is a corrected solution.

```
streakCount = 0 # Counts the longest current streak
streakIndex = 0 # Keeps track of where the streak started
for n in range(len(data)):
    if data['Activity'].loc[n] = 0:
        if streakCount == 0:
            streakIndex = n
        streakCount += 1
    elif data['Activity'].loc[n] > 0:
        if streakCount > 60:
            for i in range(streakIndex,streamIndex+streakCount): # loop to Nan out the range of 0's
                data['Activity'].loc[i] = float('nan')
        streakCount = 0 # reset streak
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look at my problem and suggesting a solution. Your code seems to work for the first period of >60 minutes of no activity. It did not detect a second round. I do not understand the "range(index, amount)" part so I suspect that the problem is somewhere there? 

I introduced two 80-line periods of 0-activity in the original csv file. This new file can be found here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cko6990vuqsgkuz/TNW.csv?dl=0
note: TNW(.csv) stands for "Test Non-Wear". 

Whether or not you are going to help me further: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @RobHenst Yes you are correct that is where the problem is, I had that loop wrapped in another function that took and index and amount. However I took it out because it was really small code chunk. I did not test before submitting that change. I have updated to the corrected solution.

Comment: Hi Sookool99, Sorry for my belated gratitude. The code works perfectly! Thank you so much for spending time and energy on figuring out a solution for my problem. I sincerely appreciate it! Best regards, Rob.

Comment: Just a note to myself and anyone else who wants to use the code above: In the last for-loop, n should be replaced by i.